# Convert an byte array to MD5 Hash in react native

Tags: c#, react-native, encryption, md5

I have a system in C# which receives a password and this password is encrypted into a MD5 Hash using this function. I had read a lot of posts and suggestion, but I couldn't create the MD5 byte array as in C#.

```cs
public static string GetMD5HashData(string data)
{
    //create new instance of md5
    MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();

    //convert the input text to array of bytes
    byte[] hashData = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(data));

    //create new instance of StringBuilder to save hashed data
    StringBuilder returnValue = new StringBuilder();

    //loop for each byte and add it to StringBuilder
    for (int i = 0; i < hashData.Length; i++)
    {
        returnValue.Append(hashData[i].ToString());
    }

    // return hexadecimal string
    return returnValue.ToString();
}
```

The return of this function is this string **207154234292557519022585191701391052252168** . I need to generate the same string in React Native.
This part **Encoding.Default.GetBytes(data)** in the **C#** function I've reproduced in React native, ***so both C# and React native return the same array of bytes from the input string***.

> Input string: 'system123' byte array: '[115, 121, 115, 116, 101, 109,
> 49, 50, 51]'

The React native function to generate the array of bytes.

```js
convertStringToByteArray = (str) =>{
    var bufferedVal = Buffer.from(str, 'utf8').toString('hex');
    String.prototype.encodeHex = function () {
        var bytes = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
            bytes.push(this.charCodeAt(i));
        }
    
        return bytes;
    };
   
    var byteArray = str.encodeHex();
    return byteArray;
};
```

I've tried some libs like crypto-js for react-native to create the MD5 hash, but could not generate the same value as C# '**207154234292557519022585191701391052252168**'. Could someone help me?

Comment: The JavaScript implementation depends strongly on the used crypto library, e.g. with CryptoJS it's only a few lines of code. Which crypto library do you use? You should also verify that the C# environment really applies Utf8, otherwise problems generally occur with non-ASCII characters, s. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=net-6.0#remarks).

Comment: I've made some tests on C#  about the encoding on the app. The encoding UTF8 returns the same value as default encoding. The libs I had tried are 'react-native-md5','react-native-crypto-js';'js-md5'

Comment: An MD5 hash would be 32 hexadecimal digits.  With `returnValue.Append(hashData[i].ToString());` you are producing 42 _decimal_ digits, so of course they'll never match.  You need to use `returnValue.AppendFormat("x2", hashData[i]);` or `returnValue.Append(hashData[i].ToString("x2"));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying CryptoJS and assuming UTF8 encoding, the C# logic can be implemented as follows:

```js
var result = '';
var hashBytes = CryptoJS.MD5('system123').toString(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1);
for (var i = 0; i < hashBytes.length; i++) 
    result += hashBytes.codePointAt(i).toString();
console.log(result); // 207154234292557519022585191701391052252168
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Explanation:
`CryptoJS.MD5()` implicitly performs a UTF-8 encoding since the data is passed as string ([here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-hashing-input)). The [Latin1 encoder](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders) converts the `WordArray` into a bytes string. In the loop, the Unicode code point value for each byte is determined as non-negative integer, converted to a string, and concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you use a different encoding in your C# code compared to your js code.
Try to use `Encoding.UTF8` instead of `Encoding.Default` in your code.

```
public static string GetMD5HashData(string data)
{
    //create new instance of md5
    MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();

    //convert the input text to array of bytes
    byte[] hashData = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));

    //create new instance of StringBuilder to save hashed data
    StringBuilder returnValue = new StringBuilder();

    //loop for each byte and add it to StringBuilder
    for (int i = 0; i < hashData.Length; i++)
    {
        returnValue.Append(hashData[i].ToString());
    }

    // return hexadecimal string
    return returnValue.ToString();

}
```

Comment: I can't change the C# code because this hash is already in a production database. What I really need is to reproduce the same in React Native

Comment: You need to figure out what encoding is being used on the server where your c# program runs. Then you want to use that encoding in your React app. But just as a heads-up, it is advised to NOT use MD5 as hashing algorithm to store passwords or other sensitive information since it is relatively easy to reverse back to it's original.

Comment: Oh, and why would you want to encrypt the password on the client side? HTTPS will make sure it will arrive safely on your server.

Comment: I have an offline app which will use the same data from the original app but with an offline database. And the users already have their passwords registered. The original app communicate with an API which does the comparison of the hash on the server side.